# Titanium: Video player data source from database

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

So, i would like to put an mp3 file in a DB blob, and play it from there.

I can see that the video object supports a blob, but it appears it's a file blob?

```
var blobStream = Ti.Stream.createStream({ source: myBlob, mode: Ti.Stream.MODE_READ });
var newBuffer = Ti.createBuffer({ length: myBlob.length });
var bytes = blobStream.read(newBuffer);
```

Additionally, it supports a file or text metod:

```
text : StringREADONLY
UTF-8 string representation of the data in this blob.
file : Titanium.Filesystem.FileREADONLY
File object represented by this blob, or null if this blob is not associated with a file
```

Does this mean i can specify the blob as a string?

Comment: I think it would be better to store the mp3 in Application data directory and keep its link in the database, and use the url to play the song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, you can use media property and set [Media object to play, as either a File, a Blob, or a URL.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer-property-media), but it is better a multiplatform property like url.

So the best answer is:

1. Read DB and get Blob
2. Write Blob to temporal file at [FileSystem](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem-method-createTempFile)
3. Set File Path to [url property of VideoPlayer](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer-property-url)

I hope my answer helps you :)

Comment: I was afraid this was the case, but i wanted to make sure :)